# Load the OS from SD card which is purposed to run on Raspberry, on my computer

Tags: linux, ssh, python, raspberry-pi, sd-card

I have an SD card where I want to write an OS for my Raspberry, then I want to do some modifications to its files, like create Python code files there in a convenient manner, install libs and packages.

Can I after creating a bootable SD card with, e.g. NOOBS or Raspbian, load it in a virtual machine on a Mac or directly access its files? Does it make sense and will it make the life easier or are there other preferred ways, like booting it from the real Raspberry and connect via SSH?

Comment: If you can find a hypervisor ( VirtualBox, VMWare, ect. ) that supports ARM this indeed should be possible.  Please note both of those examples are not ARM hypervisors.  It might be easier to load the image, play with the image, then just export the image after you have configured it.

Comment: An hypervisor can't run a different archiecture than it's host's running. Only an emulator can do it. Try Qemu

Comment: You almost always want to do this via SSH.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Debian to your Mac, or a virtual machine. Debian can read bootable SD card.

You can also use OSXFUSE to mount ext4 partition directly without virtual machine. I don't tried that, but it should work.

And yes, it's easier to transfer files with ftp or samba. I recommend putting a ftp server to your mac, and use wget to transfer files through your network.